# private symfony bundle on bitbucket, recipe on github not found by composer

Tags: symfony, composer-php, bitbucket, bundle, recipe

I'm using a private symfony bundle, which I have stored on bitbucket. 
In the composer.json of the module that imports the lib, I have:

```
"repositories": {
    "symfony-lib": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git@bitbucket.org:myCompany/symfony-lib.git"
    }
}
```

Composer finds it and all is good.
But I also created a recipe for it (and that must be on github, not on bitbucket). I made a pull request for the recipe, and it was merged, i.e. the recipe is fine.

But when I now do

```
composer req myCompany/symfony-lib:1.1
```

composer imports the lib, but doesn't find the recipe and just creates a default recipe.

Expected behaviour: composer finds and executes the recipe. 
 
Actual behaviour: composer doesn't find the recipe

Comment: Either your package is on packagist or you have declared a different kind of repository. But without more details is hard to answer this question.

Comment: Could you please go into more detail? If I understand correctly your bundle is in a private repository on bitbucket. I assume you have added a repository to your project's `composer.json` in order to fetch it? Since your recipe is public, would you mind linking to it? What is the output when you run `composer require` with additional debug output ( `-vvv`) when loading the recipes? Is your package listed inside `symfony.lock`?

Comment: Did you check https://blog.mayflower.de/6851-symfony-4-flex-private-recipes.html?

Comment: @qdequippe, thanks for the hint. Yes that articale was actually the one that inspired me.